# Problem with opening big file because the offset is larger than the node's length

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I have an interesting issue when I want to open a minimised JS file (in my case [swaper.min.js](https://swiperjs.com/)) inside [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

The editor is returning an error with below information:

```
Unable to open 'swiper.min.js': Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': The offset 138203 is larger than the node's length (65536)..
```

I assume that we can change somewhere the value of length for Node or maybe there is another solution..?

Comment: If you are interested in looking at the code I would suggest you look at the none minified version, because even if you could open this file, with it been minimised it's not going to be fun..  https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/package/js/swiper.js  . Even better would be to look at the none packaged src -> https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/tree/master/package/src

Comment: good point @Keith.. I know that checking to the minified code is a ninja approach.. I would rather know how we can solve the problem..

Comment: You could maybe post an issue here -> https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

Comment: Thanks @Keith - it is not a bad idea and I found already the same problem there: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90391